# Calculate rank for multiple columns using loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data as following,

| Company | rev | eps | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 23.5 | 20.5 | 40.5 |
| c2 | 21.5 | 23.5 | 25.5 |
| c3 | 40.5 | 32.5 | 20.5 |

My expected output is:

| Company | rev | eps | profit | rev_rank | eps_rank | profit_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 23.5 | 20.5 | 40.5 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| c2 | 21.5 | 23.5 | 25.5 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| c3 | 40.5 | 32.5 | 20.5 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

I have tried following output,

```
for i8 in list(growth_rank):
    '{}'.format(i8)+"_rank"= growth_rank[i8].rank(ascending=False)
    growth_rank.append(i8)
```

it says that I cannot assign operator.

How to change the code? I know instead of looping I can simply try with following code,

```
growth_rank['rev_rank'] = growth_rank['rev'].rank(ascending=False)
```

But how to loop through the data and assign/create a new column of rank accordingly using loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f-string`s for assign all columns without first selected by indexing `[1:]`:

```
for i8 in growth_rank.columns[1:]:
    growth_rank[f"{i8}_rank"]= growth_rank[i8].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
print (growth_rank)
  Company   rev   eps  profit  rev_rank  eps_rank  profit_rank
0      c1  23.5  20.5    40.5         2         3            1
1      c2  21.5  23.5    25.5         3         2            2
2      c3  40.5  32.5    20.5         1         1            3
```

Or processing all columns without first selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and appedn to original with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = growth_rank.iloc[:, 1:].rank(ascending=False).astype(int).add_suffix('_rank')
df = growth_rank.join(df1)
print (df)
  Company   rev   eps  profit  rev_rank  eps_rank  profit_rank
0      c1  23.5  20.5    40.5         2         3            1
1      c2  21.5  23.5    25.5         3         2            2
2      c3  40.5  32.5    20.5         1         1            3
```