# How to add new column by getting the data from each?

Tags: pandas

I have Dataframe:

```
teamId      pts xpts    
Liverpool   82  59
Man City    57  63
Leicester   53  47
Chelsea     48  55
```

And I'm trying to add new columns that identify the team position by each column

I wanna get this:

```
teamId      pts xpts №pts №xpts    
Liverpool   82  59   1    2
Man City    57  63   2    1
Leicester   53  47   3    4
Chelsea     48  53   4    3
```

I tried to do something similar with the following code, but to no avail. The result is a list

```
df = [df.sort_values(by=i, ascending=False).assign(new_col=lambda x: range(1, len(df) + 1)) for i in df.columns]
```

Comment: I found answer to the similar question.. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66884840)

Comment: `teamId` is index or column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
df[["no_pts", "no_xpts"]] = df.apply(lambda x: np.argsort(-x)) + 1
```

We pass each column but negated so that it gives the *ascending* order sort's indices. Since it starts from 0, we add 1 at the end.

to get

```
           teamId  pts xpts  no_pts  no_xpts
Liverpool      82        59       1        2
Man City       57        63       2        1
Leicester      53        47       3        4
Chelsea        48        55       4        3
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions if `teamId` is index:

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with all columns, add prefix and append to original DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(df.rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int).add_prefix('no_'))
print (df)
           pts  xpts  no_pts  no_xpts
teamId                               
Liverpool   82    59       1        2
Man City    57    63       2        1
Leicester   53    47       3        4
Chelsea     48    55       4        3
```

If need specify columns for processing use `list`:

```
cols = ['pts','xpts']
df = df.join(df[cols].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int).add_prefix('no_'))
```